# Using ES6 in Nodejs without transpiling code

Tags: node.js, ecmascript-6, babeljs, ecmascript-5

I am using Nodejs v9.0.0. I have to use Babel for transpiling the code into ES5 because if not transpiled it throws error `unexpected token import`. So If anyone know how to use the real ES6 version in nodejs and which nodejs version. Please let me know.

Thanks

Comment: Install Node v10.9.0. v9 does not support ES6 module syntax.

Comment: If you want to resolve `unexpected token import` issue refer to this [link](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html)

Comment: I am using a SDK which requires Nodejs 9.0 not above that. Is it possible to use ES6 with Node v9.0.0?

Answer (score 2):

All es6 is supported by NodeJS since 8.10 version : look at [the column NodeJS in the es6 compatibility array](https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/).
Unforfunately the ES6 Module syntax is not supported or [only with the flag experimental](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html).

So you need to convert your ESModule in CJSModule. You can do it with the [babel-plugin-transform-es2015-modules-commonjs](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-es2015-modules-commonjs/) plugin

In your .babelrc file :

```
"plugins": [
    "transform-es2015-modules-commonjs"
]
```

If you use [babel-register](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-register) the transformation occurs when the file is required(imported)